# Where can I find SSR and/or SNPs that locate RC1 genes in Soybean?

Tags: bioinformatics

Where should I look to find SSR and/or SNPs that locate RC1 genes in Soybean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SoyBase](http://soybase.org/snps/) has Illumina SoySNP50K iSelect BeadChip and they've identified soy SNVs. You could find them in [dbSNP](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/SNP/) - identifiers starts with 'ss'.